# Mathematics formula expression of finding cliques

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I am actually trying to write a math expression of finding a clique with size *x*. I can tell it in English, but somehow it is hard for me to translate it into a math expression.

In a graph, *G* = (*V(G)*, *E(G)*). If we need to find a clique with size *x* means to check if there exists *x* vertices, $V_1, V_2, ..., V_x$, such that .....

and then I do not know how to write a math expression to tell such that every node in $\{V_1, V_2, ..., V_x\}$ must have a link to every other node in $\{V_1, V_2, ..., V_x\}$ and all links must also belong to *E(G)*.

Comment: How is your $E(G)$ represented? a list of couples? a symmetric matrix?

Comment: V(G) means all vertices in G, while E(G) means all edges in G.

Comment: Yes, but you need a structure on $E(G)$ to be able to use its elements in a math expression. How do you denote an element in $E(G)$?

Comment: (V1, V2) belongs to E(G) means V1 and V2 are connected in graph G.

Comment: So if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are connected by an edge, then $(V_1,V_2),(V_2,V_1)\in E(G)$? Is your graph directed or undirected?

Comment: Undirected graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E(G)$ is the set of unordered pairs $\{V_a,V_b\}$ of vertices $V_a,V_b\in V(G)$ that are connected by an edge, then you could finish your sentence as follows:

> ... such that $\{V_i,V_j\}\in E(G)$ for all $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,x\}$ with $i\neq j$.

You might also want to emphasize that the vertices $V_1$, ..., $V_x$ should be distinct. You could also check

> ... if there exists $C\subset V(G)$ with $|C|=x$ and $\{a,b\}\in E(G)$ for all distinct $a,b\in C$.

Comment: It looks good! Thanks a lot!! So your answer is for undirected graph?

Comment: May I ask which one is for undirected graph? Thz

Comment: Yes, because the pairs in $E(G)$ are unordered, i.e. the edges have no direction.